# Why is magic acid a superacid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

[image]

The above is a representation of magic acid. The left part is the acid; the right part is the solvent. Why would this combination make for a particularly good acid?

The left part looks like a sulfuric acid derivative, except one of the oxygens has been replaced by an electronegative fluorine. Why can't we replace *all* the oxygens with fluorines? Wouldn't that make for an even *stronger* acid through inductive stabilization of negative charge after proton loss?

Also, does the solvent play a role in magic acid's acidity? Does the highly partially positive Sb central atom play a role in stabilizing negative charge on the solute after the solute has been deprotonated?

Comment: Fluorosulfuric acid is already stronger than H2SO4 - that means pure HSO3F is already a superacid. Addition of even small amount of SbF5 makes it much stronger, still.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The explanation is that sufficiently strong Lewis acids like $\ce{SbF5}$ will form adducts even with very weak, traditionally non-coordinating Lewis bases like $\ce{SO3F-}$. The resulting anionic complexes are extremely stable, with the negative charge distributed over a large, highly polarizable molecule and inductively stabilized by the fluorine atoms. The formation of this complex, in turn, promotes the autoprotolysis equilibrium:

$$\ce{HSO3F + HSO3F <=> SO3F- + H2SO3F+}$$

The protonated species above is the most active molecule in sufficiently concentrated solutions. (In reality, the composition of these mixtures may be much more complex, with dimers of the form $\ce{Sb2F10(SO3F)-}$ and possibly more complex oligomeric structures. See, for example, this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=2g49AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA344&lpg=PA345#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

While there are some more recent and exotic examples of such Brønsted/Lewis acid mixtures, the idea is actually a fairly old one. Perhaps the most common example: sulfur trioxide in sulfuric acid gives a solution known as oleum, which contains a proportion of [disulfuric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrosulfuric_acid) molecules. The resulting mixture is considerably more acidic than pure sulfuric acid alone and has various uses in industrial applications as well as laboratory-scale synthetic organic chemistry.

As for why the oxygens cannot be subsituted with fluorines to yield an even stronger acid system, I can only give a speculative answer. It seems to me that a hypothetical molecule such as, e.g., $\ce{SF3OH}$ (if this is what you're imagining) would probably be very liable to decompose:

$$\ce{SF3OH -> SOF2 + HF}$$

In any case, I can find absolutely no relevant literature, which in and of itself says something about the stability of such a molecule (or perhaps my ineptitude, as the case may be).

Comment: Isn't sulfuric acid such a strong acid because of the delocalization effect? Replacing oxygen with fluorine would then only decrease the acidity.

Comment: @Jori, I was addressing Dissenter's secondary question as to why sulfuric acid derivatives with all but one $\ce{-OH}$ replaced aren't seen (and probably don't exist). Yes, the structure with oxygens has an advantage in polarizability over fluorines, but (to the best of my knowledge) inductive through-bond and through-space effects are chiefly influenced by electronegativity, similarly for any negative hyperconjugation that may exist, and fluorine is dominant there. The molecules in question are purely hypothetical, so I really have no definitive answer.

Answer (score 14):

> Why is magic acid a superacid?

Because it meets the [definition of a superacid](http://goldbook.iupac.org/S06135.html): A medium having a high acidity, generally greater than that of 100 wt.% sulfuric acid

> Why would this combination make for a particularly good acid?

I'm simplifying a bit, but let's examine the following equilibrium (it is one of the early equilibria involved in the formation of Magic acid)
$$\ce{HSO_{3}F + SbF5 <=> H^+ + [SbF_{5}-O-SO_{2}F]^-}$$
The extreme stability of the hexacoordinate antimony anion is what drives the equilibrium to the right.

> Why can't we replace all the oxygens with fluorines?

First, the oxygen(s) is used to coordinate to the $\ce{SbF_5}$ structures.  In some structures there is coordination to multiple $\ce{SbF5}$ units through multiple oxygens.  In other structures the oxygens have been removed and replaced with fluorine. Also, you need at least one oxygen so you can have a proton. The equilibria that occur in magic acid are very complex and not entirely understood (for example, [see p 52](http://books.google.com/books?id=BH2vPZBIUXcC&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=Chemistry%20in%20super%20acids%20II,%20commeyras,%20olah&source=bl&ots=PJcREh-vRl&sig=_0x88Ff6y08ZnoGYitOfzCfGH04&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fnHzU6SNIIKcjAKzzoCYAw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=equilibria&f=false))

> does the solvent play a role in magic acid's acidity?

There is no solvent.

Comment: I thought the antimony complex was the solvent

Comment: Also why would the complex be stable ? Induction?

Comment: "I thought the antimony complex was the solvent"  I misunderstood, I thought you meant some traditional solvent.  "why would the complex be stable"  With all of the oxygens and fluorines inductive effects must play a role.  I also suspect that the Sb is playing a role.

Comment: @ron " I misunderstood, I thought you meant some traditional solvent" Don't you wish to  update your answer according to that misunderstanding?

Comment: @GaurangTandon  I think it is a useful answer as is.

Comment: @ron Your answer says in the end "There is no solvent." and then you've acknowledged a misunderstanding in the comments...

Comment: @GaurangTandon  I understand, but it is still an answer to a related question and can broaden the readers understanding.

Comment: @ron What is the solvent if the equilibrium constant of the above reaction is very big?

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the answers of ron and Greg E. I just want to add another concept, that was not mentioned so far: [non-coordinating anions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-coordinating_anion). You can stop reading here or continue and see a short summary.

As a second remark, it is important to know, that [fluorosulfuric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorosulfuric_acid) is already a [superacid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superacid).

---

Acidity is strongly dependent on the strength of the proton-conjugated-base bond. Basically stating, the weaker the bond, the higher is the acidity.

All currently known superacids operate on this principle and "[magic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_acid)" is one of the strongest. The reason for the extraordinary acidity is the high potency of [antimony pentafluoride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony_pentafluoride) as a lewis acid. It will coordinate to almost anything with electrons, especially itself in liquid phase, forming chain oligo-/polymers $\ce{[SbF5]_{n}}$ with a length between $\ce{n=5-10}$.

If there is something more potent than this, it will go for it. Antimony pentafluoride is a very dangerous substance. This is exactly what is happening in magic acid, forming weakly or non-coordinating anions as conjugated base.
$$\ce{SbF5 + 2 HSO3F <=> H2SO3F+ + [SbF5SO3F]^{-}}.$$
Now this is a fairly large anion with a highly delocalised (due to symmetry constraints) charge. With excess of antimony pentafluoride, even larger anions can be formed, which is the case when used as a solvent.
$$\ce{[SbF5SO3F]^{-} + SbF5 <=> [(SbF5)2SO3F]^{-}}$$
In essence, $\ce{SbF5}$ is shifting the equilibrium of autodissociation of $\ce{HSO3F}$ to the right, creating much greater concentration of $\ce{H2SO3F+}$ - that's protonated fluorosulfuric acid - much stronger than the neutral molecule. It's strong enough to protonate aliphatic hydrocarbons to form carbocations.

There is another superacid, using the same concept, which is even stronger: [fluoroantimonic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid). It is in principle that, what you already suggested, substituting the oxygens by fluorines. Instead of $\ce{HSO3F}$, hydrofluoric acid $\ce{HF}$ is used, giving rise to the (to date) most powerful acid. It also makes use of the high affinity of $\ce{SbF5}$ towards fluoride anions.
$$\ce{2SbF5 + 2 HF <=> H2F+ + [Sb2F11]- }$$
$\ce{H2F+}$ is even stronger acid than $\ce{H2SO3F+}$ - it can protonate water *twice*, [even if transiently](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/49223/9961).

Comment: This "naked proton" idea is lame, but I also thought it's right years ago :( In fluoroantimonic it's "just" H2F+ (or even bigger cations). And in magic it's still OH, even if perhaps more polarised.

Comment: @Mithoron yes, probably. I don't think it completely invalidates the answer though. So, maybe rework it, but that needs time; which I don't have. :(

Comment: OK, I edited it. Check if you think it's OK.

Comment: @Mithoron thanks! That was not on my radar anymore, and holy cow is that stuff like...

Comment: Oh, I stumbled upon it again, because of the new superacidic question.