# Can H4O 2+ form?

Tags: acid-base, water, ions, osmosis

Like $\ce{NH4+}$ ,Is there any possibility of formation of $\ce{H4O^{2+}}$ (of tetrahedral structure)?

[image]

My theory is: it can be formed by osmosis setup where heavy acids like $\ce{H3PO4}$ or $\ce{H2S2O7}$ are passed through a semipermeable membrane like **gelatinous copper ferrocyanide SPM**, which allow only small ions like H+ to pass.

This then could form $\ce{H3O+}$, then its lone pair could attack the excess $\ce{H+}$ in solution to form forming $\ce{H4O^{2+}}$.

Comment: Semipermeable membranes just don't work like that. You **can't** separate cations from anions this way, and that's a very, very huge "**can't**" (as in _"a mosquito can't lift the Empire State Building"_).
The possible (?) existence of $\ce{H4O^2+}$ in extreme conditions is another story.

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24342/what-is-the-ka-of-oh-and-kb-of-h3o

Comment: Osmosis can reject anions as stated in [rejection of anions by osmosis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001191649185055Y)  @IvanNeretin

Comment: Sure, but it would also place another ions instead of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The existence of $\ce{H4O^{2+}}$ has been inferred from hydrogen/deuterium isotopic exchange monitored through $\ce{^{17}O}$ NMR spectroscopy in the most extremely acidic condensed phase superacid we can make, [fluoroantimonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid) ($\ce{HF:SbF5}$ or $\ce{HSbF6}$). It seems that even the slightly weaker but still very much superacidic [magic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_acid) $\ce{HSO3F:SbF5}$ is not strong enough to effect measurable protonation of $\ce{H3O+}$ into $\ce{H4O^{2+}}$. It likely also can exist in the gas phase by exposing water to bare protons, and might have some importance in astrochemistry. Relatedly, $\ce{H4S^{2+}}$ also has been inferred to exist through the same type of measurements, and is easier to make, existing in magic acid mixtures.

A nice source for your superacidic needs is books by George Olah, the father of superacidic chemistry. In particular, [Onium Ions](http://wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471148776.html) has a section on the protohydronium dication $\ce{H4O^{2+}}$ on page 435. There are many other curious cations analyzed such as $\ce{CH6^{2+}}$ and even $\ce{CH7^{3+}}$. When it comes to superacids, nothing is sacred!

Comment: Minor point.  Fluoroantimonic acid is not $\ce{HSbF6}$.  The fluoroantimonate anion is such a weak proton acceptor that it never gets protonated at all; therefore the acid forms only ionic species.  See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid) for a description of these ionic species.