# Do quaternary sulfur dications exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, ions, organosulfur-compounds

We know that sulfur can form sulfides $\ce{R2S}$, with two substituents bonded to it. The simplest example of this would be hydrogen sulfide.

However, sulfur can also form sulfonium ions $\ce{R3S+}$, where 3 substituents are attached to the sulfur atom and a negatively-charged counteranion is present.

What I am asking is whether there is such a thing as sulfur bonded to 4 substituents, with each bond being a single bond, with 2 counteranions (either $\ce{(R4S^2+)(X^2-)}$ or $\ce{(R4S^2+)(X^-)2}$). Is there such a thing as that or something similar?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112087/why-doesnt-h%e2%82%84o%c2%b2%e2%81%ba-exist

Comment: There are even tertiary dications = carbene analogues. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja9073968

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ogawa et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1039/C39920001141)] were first to report a crystal structure (CSD-YAFNOI) of a compound with quaternary sulfur, **bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane**:

[image: bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane crystal structure]

**Figure 1**. Molecular structure of bis(2,2'-biphenylene)sulfurane (CSD-YAFNOI). Color code: $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$; $\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$; $\color{#FFFF30}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{S}$.

> Compound **1** was synthesized as follows (Scheme 1). Dibenzothiophene 5-oxide (200 mg, 1.0 mmol) in anhydrous tetrahydrofuran (THF, 10 ml) was treated with trimethylsilyl trifluoromethanesulfonate (0.25 ml, 1.3 mmol) under an $\ce{N2}$ atmosphere at −78 °C. After stirring at 0 °C for 30 min, the
>   mixture was cooled to −78 °C and was treated with $\pu{1.0 mol dm-3}$ 2,2'-dilithiobiphenyl (1.0 ml, 1.0 mmol) in diethyl ether solution. The whole mixture was stirred at −78 °C for 1 h and at 0 °C for 30 min under an $\ce{N2}$ atmosphere. After evaporation of the solvent, the residue was washed with anhydrous diethyl ether (10 ml) and was extracted with anhydrous benzene (10 ml) under an $\ce{N2}$ atmosphere. The solvent was removed under reduced pressure, and the crude product was recrystallized from anhydrous THF at −20 °C to give **1** as orange rods in 96% yield.
>
> [image: bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane synthesis]
>
> **Scheme 1** *Reagents*: i, trimethylsilyl trifluoromethansulfonate in THF;
>   ii, 2,2'-dilithiobiphenyl in diethyl ether-THF

Further work by Sato et al. [[2](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja971336k)] resulted in a synthesis and crystal structure (CSD-NEDCEE) of **bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfuranyl bis(tetrafluoroborate)**.

Structurally, it's a similar compound with a greater, nearly 90° (in contrast to 60° twist angle in neutral bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane), twist angle between 2,2′-biphenylylene ligands, however water molecules and $\ce{[BF4]}$-counterions appear heavily disordered:

[image: bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfuranyl bis(tetrafluoroborate) crystal structure fragment]

**Figure 2**. Fragment of the molecular structure of bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfuranyl bis(tetrafluoroborate) (CSD-NEDCEE) showing the bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfuranyl cation. Oxygen atoms from water molecules as well as tetrafluoroborate anions are omitted for clarity. Color code: $\color{#EEEEEE}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{H}$; $\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$; $\color{#FFFF30}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{S}$.

> Recently, we have succeeded in the first isolation and structural determination of bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane [10-S-4(C4)] (**1**) as a stable sulfurane(IV) having only carbon ligands.[…] We considered that this sulfurane would be a suitable precursor to provide the desired dication. Therefore, we tried the reaction of bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane (**1**) with xenon difluoride ($\ce{XeF2}$) in the presence of $\ce{BF3 * OEt2}$ and indeed obtained the bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane dication, [8-S4(C4)]²⁺ (**2**) as an amazingly stable bis(tetrafluoroborate) salt.[…] Here, we communicate the first isolation and structural determination of bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane dication (**2**) having only carbon ligands. […]
>
> The sulfurane **1** was reacted with 1 mol equiv of xenon difluoride in the presence of $\ce{BF3 * OEt2}$ in dry $\ce{CH3CN}$ at −40 °C (Scheme 1). After the solvent was removed at room temperature, the residue was washed with $\ce{CHCl3}$ at room temperature, and bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane bis(tetrafluoroborate) (**2**) was isolated as a stable moisture-insensitive yellow powder in 62% yield.
>
> [image: bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)sulfurane bis(tetrafluoroborate) synthesis]
>
> **Scheme 1**

Subsequently, hexacoordinated derivatives – **bis(2,2′-biphenylylene)dimethyl-** and **diphenylpersulfuranes** – were synthesized and their molecular structures were elucidated [[3](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja060497y)].

#### References

1. Ogawa, S.; Matsunaga, Y.; Sato, S.; Iida, I.; Furukawa, N. First Preparation of a Sulfurane with Four Carbon–Sulfur Bonds: Synthesis and Molecular Structure of Bis(2,2′-Biphenylylene)Sulfurane. *J. Chem. Soc., Chem. Commun.* **1992**, 0 (16), 1141–1142. https://doi.org/10.1039/C39920001141.
2. Sato, S.; Ameta, H.; Horn, E.; Takahashi, O.; Furukawa, N. First Isolation and Molecular Structure of Bis(2,2′-Biphenylylene)Sulfuranyl Bis(Tetrafluoroborate) [8−S−4(C4)]²⁺. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1997**, 119 (50), 12374–12375. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja971336k.
3. Sato, S.; Matsunaga, K.; Horn, E.; Furukawa, N.; Nabeshima, T. Isolation and Molecular Structure of the Organo-Persulfuranes [12−S−6(C6)]. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2006**, 128 (21), 6778–6779. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja060497y.