# Reaction between an acid and acid

Tags: acid-base

My initial thought was that the stronger acid will act as an acid and the weaker acid as base like the reaction between $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ but in this reaction there is a lone pair available for protonation, what if the lone pair was not present , will the reaction still occur? Is the answer dependent on what the acids exactly are?

Comment: Can you give an example of acid where the lone pair is not present?

Comment: I meant an acid in which lone pair is unavailable like in Ammonium ion(NH4+).

Comment: OK, then there will be no reaction of this type.

Comment: Being an acid and ability of acting as base are 2 independent properties. The   same for bases and their ability to act as acids.

Comment: So a stronger acid cannot protonate a weaker one(in general)?

Comment: You can, but you will need one of the acids as pure solvent; a solvent like water will just absorb the protons. For example, sulfuric acid or hydrochloric acid in glacial acetic acid. If you only want to consider protonation of acids bearing a + charge like ammonium, then this will not exist.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112087/why-doesnt-h%e2%82%84o%c2%b2%e2%81%ba-exist

Comment: @IvanNeretin There could be if strong enough acid is used (and the other "acid" is good enough base).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of $\ce{HNO3}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$, the proton from sulphuric acid protonates the $\ce{-OH}$ group of $\ce{HNO3}$ , which gives $\ce{NO2+}$ , $\ce{HSO4-}$ and water. 
This mixture of nitric acid and sulphuric acid is widely used as a [nitrating mixture](http://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Nitrating_mixture) for nitration of aromatic compounds.

In case of other acid mixtures, no reaction happens, but there is an equilibrium. The stronger acids dissociates almost completely , decreasing the dissociation of the weaker one by common ion effect.