# Do amphoteric cations exist?

Tags: acid-base

I know that anions such as $\ce{CH3COO-}, \ce{OH-}, \ce{CN-}$ are basic in nature, since they are conjugate bases of weak acids. Similarly, cations such as $\ce{NH4+}, \ce{H3O+}$ are acidic in nature , since they conjugate acids of weak bases.

However, we also have another case whereby, anions such as $\ce{HSO3-}, \ce{HS-}$ are **amphoteric** in nature. This is due to the fact that their conjugate acids are **polyprotic acids**. Thus, one can have the two reactions:

$\ce{HS- + H2O <=> S^2- + H3O+}$ and $\ce{HS- + H2O <=> H2S + OH-}$

Since, for this case, we got amphoteric anions from polyprotic acids, is there a possibility that we can do the same for polyprotic bases so as to get amphoteric cations? i.e. Can we have a **conjugate acid of a polyprotic base**, which can be regarded as an amphoteric cation? I haven't seen any such examples of amphoteric cations yet, hence I am asking this question.

Comment: Polyamines. Or basic aminoacids.

Comment: $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{H3S+}$ [are technically amphoteric](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/112087/1499) (as well as likely many others), though they're (always?) extremely weak bases. I wonder if there are more natural examples which are limited to few atoms.

Comment: Or CaOH+,  as Ca(OH)2 has 2 dissociation constants.

Comment: What about singly protonated DABCO? (ie 1,4-diazabicyclo[2.2.2]octane). It is cationic, and the neutral conjugate base has no additional acidic protons. With one proton, it is weakly basic (pKa of conjugate acid is ~3) and weakly acidic (pKa ~ 9).

Comment: Thing is, almost *any cation* can be protonated. Only the smallest ones may be to unstable to have minimum on PES. Another thing is that "amphoteric" tends to be used for stuff easily / commonly acting as acid and base, so what exactly you'd like to get here?

Comment: Your bolded text isn't entirely clear: the examples you cited, like $\ce{HS-}$, already satisfy this requirement. For example, $\ce{HS-}$ is the conjugate acid of $\ce{S^2-}$, which is a polyprotic base. I assume you want this polyprotic base to be a neutral species, and not a negatively charged species. But the other examples given in the comments already suit that perfectly well. A molecule with multiple amine groups is the simplest and most common example.

Comment: @Poutnik: Isn't Ca(OH)2 a strong base? No dissociation constant?

Comment: Diamines, triamines, etc. There are commercial polyamines that are used as thickeners.

Comment: @James Gaidis Pkb1 = 1.37, pKb2 = 2.43
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_hydroxide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for example [lysine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysine).

Lysine has two amino groups and one carboxyl group. When dissolved in aprotic solvents, all of these will be uncharged so the carboxyl group will be $\ce{-COOH}$ and the two amino groups $\ce{-NH2}$. When dissolved in water, these three groups have distinct $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values of $2.15, 9.16$ and $10.67$. Depending on the acidity of the solution, the following (acid-sided) equilibriums occur:

[image: Two deprotonations of lysine dication]

When dissolved in water, the carboxyl group’s proton will immediately be removed and used to immediately protonate the ε-amino group (the far end). However, the α-amino group is still more basic than water and thus will be partially protonated; meaning that the right-hand equilibrium will be happening predominantly if lysine is dissolved in water. Dissolved lysine will be a mixture of uncharged lysine and lysine cation.

When an acid such as hydrochloric acid is added, at first the α-amino group is completely protonated and then the left-hand equilibrium occurs predominantly as more and more lysine cation is converted to lysine dication.

If a base is added (such as sodium hydroxide), the ε-amino group’s proton can also be removed yielding lysine anion; I have not shown that equilibrium in the scheme above.

Lysine cation thus fits your question as it is an amphoteric cation, the conjugate acid of a dibasic compound.